# How to turn Prim's algorithm into Kruskal's algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I've implemented [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) in C (www.bubblellicious.es/prim.tar.gz) but I was just wondering how to transform this into [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm).

It seems they're quite similar, but I can't imagine how can I modify my old code into that new one. It'd be delicious if you give some advices or something. I know that's easy, but I'm still a n00b in C programming ...

Comment: You are much more likely to get a useful response if you post the relevant code inline in the question. Prim's algorithm is only four lines of pseudo-code so I can't believe that a tarball of half a dozen files is necessary.

Comment: Well, you can read only the main file, coz it's no necessary to look at all the files.

Comment: IMHO those algorithms aren't similar enough that it's profitable to convert from one to the other -- Prim's requires some sort of priority queue, while Kruskal's involves a global sorted list of edges. You're better off starting from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just write Kruskal's from scratch and see how they compare in your own solutions? Best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

To convert you need a forest (i.e. a set of trees where initially each node is a tree) as your temporary output structure rather than a single tree. Then on each step, rather than finding the cheapest vertex that adds a currently unconnected node to your tree, you find the cheapest edge in the graph and, if it creates a new tree (i.e. connects two previously unconnected nodes) add that tree to the forest and remove the source trees. Otherwise discard the edge.
A proper implementation of Kruskal is more memory intensive but less time intensive than a proper Prim implementation.

But the differences between the two are quite large. Probably all you can keep between are some helper functions and some data structures. Not a conversion, more a rewrite using more high level building blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you consider switching to C++ and using the boost graph library
(http://www.boost.org/)?

It contains very well implementations for both algorithms. Type-safe and highly performant.
See [kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/graph/doc/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.html) and [prim_minimum_spanning_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/graph/doc/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.html)